# Why does my python script crash every time I run OpenCV function?

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'm using a MacBook Air and whenever I run this code the system shows some error on a popup window with a long error message like this:

[image: pop up window after running the code]

And in the terminal it shows:

> "Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried with IDE's like PyCharm and VS Code. When I tried with Jupyter Notebook, it worked until I end the video capturing but again it crashed when I try to kill the video window.

Comment: "_the system throws some error with pop up window with large error msg_" : What error message is displayed in the popup window? It works OK as-is my Mac, from VS Code and straight from Terminal. What is your Mac OS version?

Comment: i added error screenshot, mac version is catalina, error popping in both the editors, vs code and pycharm, but it jupyter notebook runs til video capturing but when i press "q" it crash's then i have to use "Force Quit"

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running out of memory.

Comment: i have 35GB free space in my device

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Catalina and I can't reproduce your error, but starting Mojave, Apple now requires users to explicitly allow applications to access the camera.

See [Control access to your camera on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-euro/guide/mac-help/mchlf6d108da/10.15/mac/10.15):

> Some apps and websites can use your camera to take photos or video.
>   You can decide which apps are allowed to use the camera on your Mac.
>
> 1. On your Mac, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click Privacy.
> 2. Select Camera.
> 3. Select the tickbox next to an app to allow it to access your camera.
>
>    Deselect the tickbox to turn off access for that app.

Check that PyCharm and VS Code have permissions to access the camera. Furthermore, your Terminal should already have access to the camera, so if it works in the Terminal but not in IDEs, then enabling permissions for IDEs could work.